# CRUD action of one controller in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it a bad practice to create one of a CRUD action of one controller in another? For example we have two models `User`,`Post` and the following controller:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def show
           @user = User.find(params[:id])
      end

      def update_post #update action of PostsController
           Post.find(params[:post_id]).uppdate_attributes(params[:post])
      end

      def create_post #create action of PostsController
           @user = User.find(params[:id])
           @user.posts.create(params[:post])
      end
 end
```

Can/should I do like this or is there a better way ? The reason why this actions not in their own controller is that i want to manipulate posts at users page.

Comment: you keep overwriting my typo fixes. Fix them yourself then :)

Comment: please clarify, as I am not able to understand as if you are talking about `User` actions `update`, `create` and `Post` actions  `update`, `create`

Comment: "Is it a bad practice" - well, it certainly looks weird. What is post related functionality doing in user controller? This definitely violates the principle of least surprise :)

Comment: sorry,  i just updated the context

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It is a bit frustrating, isn't it? :D

Comment: @Pavan: quite frustrating, it is :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This is my question is not clear or there is simply no answer to it?

Comment: "the reason  is that i want to manipulate posts at users page" - why can't you have a form that sends data to posts controller from users page?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes, i could do like that, but if there is validation errors -then i cant just call `render "show" `  (render users page again) and list errors, because i will be in `posts` controller

Comment: @nikolay: you can. `render template: 'users/show'`

Comment: @nikolay but it seems to me that a better way would be to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` here and post users/posts in the same form.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sure, but my path will change from 'users/1' to 'posts/#post_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice and impractical to do that if you have association already. You can use `user` form and `fields_for` to create/update `posts.

You need to instantiate post with `build`, add to user model    `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and use `fields_for` in the view and user CRUD will save/update posts

```
#user controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def show
           @user = User.find(params[:id])
           @user.posts.build
      end
 end


#user model
accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts


#user/show view
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :posts do |post| %>
      <%= post.text_field :post %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```